# "error in locking authority file" isn't fixed even after removing .Xautority file

Tags: ssh, xauth

I'm using MobaXterm and I see this error:

/usr/bin/xauth:  error in locking authority file /home/myusername/.Xauthority

right after the login and I even removed the file *.Xauthority* after googling this issue and being suggested to do so, but I still do get that error! 
And I even tried to run my script ignoring it, but my script got blank. It was all gone!
Could anybody please help me with this?

Thanks in advance,

Homa

Comment: Possible 2 things: 1, do you have disk space or 2, is the `.Xauthority` file written with the permission of 400?

Comment: yes, I have because it was working just fine before. Anyway just to be sure I deleted some things and the error was still there.

Comment: And about the permission, I don't know how to check that.

Comment: Type `cd ~`, hit `Enter` and then type `ls -ltr .Xauthority`.  The permissions should be 400 or `-r--------`.

Comment: This is what I got: ls: cannot access .Xauthority: No such file or directory

Comment: Create it and try it again.